# In GIMP, how do you crop a photo without changing the aspect ratio?

Tags: gimp

I know I can go to image properties and then type in the resolution manually into crop for each image I work on, but is there a button to keep the photo's aspect ratio automatically?

Seems like this should be the default, but it instead keeps whatever you last typed in the box

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  The answer is in the GIMP documentation [on the crop tool here](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-crop.html). It's always worthwhile checking there first when you can't find something.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a solution here. What am I missing?

Comment: The "fixed aspect ratio" option in the Tool Options, or hold down Ctrl while you click and drag with the crop tool. Actually "Ctrl" looks like a possible typo. Should be Shift in GIMP 2.10 I think.